# After Imagebutton --> Webview Addmob doesn´t start

Tags: java, admob

I have a Little Problem..my App starts with a startscreen where i can choose between 3 imagebuttons to open 3 different webviews (3 URLs). In my startscreen i have my "Smart_Banner" from admob and after i click any imagebutton i Switch to the webview and in this WebView my admob disappears and it dont comes back! Do i have to rebuild a new admob advertise there? guys i need some real help!!

```
  public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
            && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private ImageButton Ilias_link;
private ImageButton Lsf_link;
private WebView mWebView;
private Context content;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Du hast leider kein Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Ilias_link = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ilias_link);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        Ilias_link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                if (savedInstanceState == null)
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://elearns02.fh-biberach.de/ilias3/login.php?target=&soap_pw=&ext_uid=&cookies=nocookies&client_id=HSBC&lang=de");
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                setContentView(mWebView);

            }



        });
        Lsf_link = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.lsf_link);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        Lsf_link.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                if (savedInstanceState == null)
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://lsf.fh-biberach.de/qisserver/rds?state=user&type=0");
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                setContentView(mWebView);



            }


        });





    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById((R.id.Mensaplan));
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Coming soon ;)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}}

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    String javascript = "javascript:document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].setAttribute('content', 'initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=10.0');";
    view.loadUrl(javascript);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}

private static final int TIME_INTERVAL = 3000;
private long mBackPressed;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    } else {
        if (mBackPressed + TIME_INTERVAL > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press back button twice to exit ;)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        mBackPressed = System.currentTimeMillis();




    }




}
```

}

Comment: really guys? nobody can help me? i thought Stack Overflow had some good programmers...

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setContentView(mWebView);` which replaces the view in your Activity with just the WebView. Ie it will remove the AdView (and everything else) first.

Comment: Instead of changing the contentView, you should have WebView elements in R.layout.activity_main and be making one of them visible

Comment: You can start a new Activity but unless it also has an AdView your ad will be hidden.

Comment: why will it be hidden?

Comment: Because your new Activity will overlay the Activity that has the AdView.

Comment: how can i prevent that?

Comment: Don't start a new Activity

Comment: this is not a good answer.. if i need to open a new activity how can i still Show up the admob activity?

Comment: @Viru as I said at the start if you want to show an AdView in your new Activity then you need to include an AdView in your new Activity.

Comment: You cannot have 2 Activities being shown at the same time.

Comment: i just build in a new Adview in my new Activity but in the logcat is written "banner is not visible"

Comment: That means that your view is not configured properly. It is not allowing space for the AdView or the AdView is hidden. But we are now far from your original question.