# Admob Banner exists but doesn´t appear in new Activity

Tags: java, admob

Guys im literally turning crazy...
In my app I start new acitivities very often. At the startscreen where my Buttons are (activity_main) I can see the admob banner but if I click on the button to start a new activity (which works pretty well) the admob doesnt appear! But it´s integrated and the logcat says that it have been loaded! 
Look here 
04-10 05:32:02.646 24153-24153 I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
04-10 05:32:02.646 24153-24153I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.

it startet the Banner but doesn´t appear in the webview activity! Why?

```
public class ilias extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;
private ImageButton Ilias_link;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ilias);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Du hast leider kein Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Ilias_link = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ilias_button);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                mWebView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
                if (savedInstanceState == null)
                    mWebView.loadUrl("https://elearns02.fh-biberach.de/ilias3/login.php?target=&soap_pw=&ext_uid=&cookies=nocookies&client_id=HSBC&lang=de");
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
                setContentView(mWebView);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Also i can see THE admob Banner in the XML file from the new activity!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After Imagebutton --> Webview Addmob doesn´t start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36487913/after-imagebutton-webview-addmob-doesn%c2%b4t-start)